# How to get the downloaded xlsx file from the api endpoint in karate?

Tags: download, xlsx, karate

I have an endpoint that downloads an xlsx file. In my test, I need to check the content of the file (not comparing the file with another file, but reading the content and checking). I am using karate framework for testing and I am trying to use apache POI for working with the excel sheet. However, the response I get from karate when calling the download endpoint is a String. For creating an excel file with POI I need an InputStream or the path to the actual file. I have tried the conversion, but it does not work.

I guess I am missing some connection here, or maybe the conversion is bad, I am new to karate and to the whole thing.
I appreciate any help, thanks!

```
 Given url baseUrl
    Given path downloadURI
     When method GET
     Then status 200
    And match header Content-disposition contains 'attachment'
    And match header Content-disposition contains 'example.xlsx'
    And match header Content-Type == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'

        * def value= FileChecker.createExcelFile(response)
        * print value
```

And the Java code:

```
public static String createExcelFile(String excel) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        InputStream stream = IOUtils.toInputStream(excel, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(stream);
        return ("Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets : ");
    }
```

When running the scenario, I get the following error: 
`javascript evaluation failed: FileChecker.createExcelFile(response), java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip entry source`

When testing the same endpoint in Postman, I am getting a valid excelsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Karate 0.9.X onwards you have a [`responseBytes`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#responsebytes) variable which will be raw bytes, which may be what you need.

```
* def value = FileChecker.createExcelFile(responseBytes)
```

And you can change your method signature to be:

```
public static String createExcelFile(byte[] excel) {}
```

You should be easily able to convert a byte array to an `InputStream` and take it from there.

P.S. just saying that it "works in Postman" is not helpful :P

Comment: Works, thanks! I was mentioning Postman just to avoid questions like maybe the file is not a valid xlsx

Answer (score 0):

TO download zip file from Karate tests as binary bite array

Scenario: To verify and get the ADCI Uri from deployment
  Given url basicURL + DeployUri +ArtifactUri
  And headers `{authorization:'#(authToken)',accept:'application/json',tenant:'#(tenantUUId)',Content-Type:'application/zip'}`
  When method get
  Then status 200
  And def responsebytes = responseBytes