# Is it possible to get response from an endpoint, while using UI automation?

Tags: karate

Similar to karate.Intercept(), instead of redirection - need the response. Trying to find an alternate way to extract text from PDF (with blob url).

Comment: besides the linked answer, my honest opinion is that you should just make a normal API call to download the file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69634109/143475